# Lifetime of class changes deployed by hot code replace

Tags: java, jvm, remote-debugging

How long do the modified classes exist in the JVM when they are changed in a remote debugging session by HCR?

Are they reset after disconnecting the remote session?

Comment: What happens to **all** classes when the JVM is restarted?

Comment: @kayaman they are reset to the version that is located in the classpath, e.g. in the jar?

Comment: They're not "reset". If you shut down a JVM, what happens to everything in the memory, including classes? Now what happens when you start the JVM and classes are needed?

Comment: Does “restarting the JVM” mean something other than “terminating the JVM (possibly followed by starting a new one)”?

Comment: @Kayman you seem to know the answer of my question, please let me know. The memory is released on termination. So it should be a "clean" start with unmodified classes. That`s what "reset" means for me.

Comment: @Holger no, that`s exactly what restarting means

Comment: So Kayaman’s comment applies, what happens to *all* classes when a JVM is “restarted”, i.e. terminated? Do you think, there are any leftovers when a process is terminated? Is there a reason to assume that modified classes behave differently? Or is there just a confusion between “class files” in the sense of files on the hard drive and “class files” in the sense of arrays inside the JVM containing bytes in the class file format?

Comment: Ok, maybe forget the option "restart". What about the "disconnection"? Are the changes still there? This is my main question.

Comment: Yes, the changes are still there. Disconnecting does not undo the class transformations (which is easy to test). Unless you use a tool which actively transforms them back when disconnecting, e.g. profiling tools usually revert their instrumentation before disconnecting.

Comment: thank you. please post as answer so I can mark it. that`s all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changed classes remain until the server is stopped. The disconnect does not 'reset' them.

Another important finding regarding HCR is, that there is a complete replacement of the modified class - not only the local changes in the method body.